# Checking if the username is available with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm using a basic registration form with AJAX, but the form is not connecting to the database. I'm obviously overlooking something.

So here's the field I want to validate.

```
Username:<input type="text" name="user" id="user" maxlength="30">
<span id="msgbox" style="display:none"/></input>
```

Then I use jQuery, here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#user").blur(function() {

        //remove all the class add the messagebox classes and start fading
        $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Checking...').fadeIn("slow");
        //check the username exists or not from ajax
        $.post("user_availability.php",{ user_name:$(this).val() },
            function(data) {
                if(data=='no') { //if username not avaiable
                    $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() {//start fading the messagebox
                        //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
                        $(this).html('This User name Already exists').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
                    });       

                } else {
                    $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() { //start fading the messagebox
                        //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
                        $(this).html('Username available to register').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900,1);   
                    });
                } // else
             } // function

        ); // $.post
    }); // blur
}); // ready
```

And I have this code, `user_availability.php`:

```
mysql_connect(localhost,$user,$password);
    or die('There is error to connect to server:-'.mysqli_connect_error());

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database);
$user_name=$_POST['user_name'];
$sql = "select * from members where username='$user_name'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))   
{
    $existing_users[] = $row['username'];
}

if (in_array($user_name, $existing_users))
{
    echo "no"; //user name is not availble
}
else
{
    echo "yes"; //user name is available
}
```

I get no database errors. The form will be more substantial, but I can't get it to work with this field. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would start by troubleshooting the php-page itself, separately. Add a bit of code to process $_GET vars as well and then check to see: Does it provide the expected response when you visit it directly?

Comment: Also, use Firebug (or a similar tool for checking request parameters) to verify that your javascript function is passing the correct parameters to the php page.

Comment: hmm... no. the problem is this. It is not connecting to the database.
I mean, when a new user enter his username and it is already in the database. It still says 'Username is available' ..but the truth is it is not available.

Comment: A note:  Don't insert variables directly into the SQL like that - it's vulnerable to SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a nitpick on the select statement.  Since you only need to get how many rows exist for the entered username you don't need to do a "select *" as depending on the number of columns in your users table you could be returning quite a bit of data.  I would revise your query to be like so:

```
$sql = "select COUNT(username) from members where username=$user_name";
```

Then you check to make sure that the result of the query equals zero.  If it does then the username is available.

I know that the above wasn't an answer to your question but just thought I would point it out since this looks to be a function that is going to get called a lot depending on the traffic on your registration form and the creativity of your visitors.

Answer (score -1):

Check your query:

```
 $sql = "select * from members where username='$user_name'";
```

I this the above query should be:

```
 $sql = "select * from members where username=$user_name";
```

Comment: No, the username is a string not a number (i would assume) so the OP definitely wants quotes

Comment: Quoted or quoteless, it's still a bad way to do it that is vulnerable to SQL injection