# Prevent display Duplicate entry in php via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

```
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$Phone = $_POST['Phone'];
$date = date("Y/m/d");
mysql_query ( "INSERT INTO example (fname,lname,Phone,date) VALUES ('$fname' ,'$lname', '$Phone', '$date')")

or die(mysql_error());
```

when i write a duplicate entry in my codes these Error will display:
my PRIMARY key is Phone.

```
  Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

but i want to check and display by JavaScript to Prevent this Error before adding data.
how is it possible? please help completely and wire source. thanks

Comment: there are plenty of examples of ajax on SO. No one wants to 'help completely and [write] source' for you, unless you are paying. Post what you have attempted.

Comment: @Sean i know but this is a bit hard for me.
i`m trying...

Comment: @Sean from where did those ajax came

Comment: Here are just 4 of many examples - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762478/check-if-username-exists-in-database-with-ajax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679998/check-username-using-ajax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393148/checking-if-the-username-is-available-with-ajax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840286/ajax-check-if-a-username-exists-return-message-if-it-does Use one of these as an example, changing 'username' to 'Phone'. more can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ajax+check+if+username+exists

Comment: @AvinashBabu what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$Phone = $_POST['Phone'];
$date = date("Y/m/d");

$query = "SELECT * FROM example WHERE Phone =    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Phone'])."'";
if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query)) > 0)
{ 
print "inuse";
} 
 else
{
 mysql_query ( "INSERT INTO example (fname,lname,Phone,date) VALUES ('$fname'   ,'$lname', '$Phone', '$date')")

or die(mysql_error());  
}
```